# What's the best way to change a restaurant website to accommodate a second location?

Tags: website-design

So I built a restaurant website about 2 years ago - its a standard site with menus, events, contact pages etc.

Now the restaurant is expanding and opening another branch in another location, the restaurant will never be a huge chain and there aren't any immediate plans to open more restaurants in other locations.

The problem is that the Menus (Tapas, Christmas, Cocktails, etc) and the events page will be different for both locations.

Do I create a new index page with 'Choose your location' Location 1 or location 2?

or

Do I introduce a top nav with drop downs - so

Menu > Location A > Menu
Menu > Location A > Tapas

Menu > Location B > Menu
Menu > Location B > Tapas

Events > Location A > 
Events > Location B >

I have researched this, but have not found any restaurant site with only 2 locations.

Comment: Juan, here's an example of a local steak house with two locations http://www.pacessteakhouse.com/ this is ok for a local restaurant but ideally you should have more content than this on the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that they are 2 different restaurants.

i'd create a simple entry page with an image/link for each of the 2 restaurants pointing to 2 different sub-sites, 1 for each restaurant.

No biggie.

Comment: +1 ...and here's [an example](http://www.wishbonechicago.com/) of more or less what's being described. There are "sub-sites" for each of the locations under catering and dining, but this also allows for some overall information, like the about menu items.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is make a template from the common elements between the two restaurants, this also works well when adding new restaurant locations.  Inside this template you will have items such as Menu, Events, Hours.  In terms of what gets pushed out to the UI I would recommend a drop down list that has the two locations.  Then you just fill in your abstracted template with the information for either of these two sites.  At the end of the day you want to keep the functionality that exists and just "paint" new information to the screen based on what the user selects.